# WPF CoerceCallback to cancel value change

Tags: c#, wpf, callback, dependency-properties

I have a textbox databound to a string with UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged. I want to only allow the user to type in integers to the textbox. I also want the integer values to have a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 60.

This code works with restricting the integer range only. After some testing I realized that the CoerceValueCallback doesn't work if I return the old value. Aka I can't cancel the property changed. Is there some way around this or another type of metadata that would work better?

I have tried canceling the change using DependencyProperty.UnsetValue as mentioned under 'Using CoerceValue to Cancel Value Changes'. It does not work. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation

```
        public static object CoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            var uc = (UserControlConnection)d;
            string s = (string)value;

            if (int.TryParse(s, out int i))
            {
                i = Math.Min(i, 60);
                i = Math.Max(i, 0);
                uc.TimeoutSeconds = i;
            }
            return uc.TimeoutSeconds.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is related to using a Textbox and UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged. The following works.

````
<TextBox Text="{Binding TimeoutSecondsString, ElementName=Parent_UC, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" TextChanged="Textbox_TextChanged"/>

private void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var be = ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
   if (be != null)
   { be.UpdateSource(); }
}

public static object CoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
   var uc = (UserControlConnection)d;
   string s = (string)value;

   if (int.TryParse(s, out int i))
   {
       i = Math.Min(i, 60);
       i = Math.Max(i, 0);
       uc.TimeoutSeconds = i;
       return uc.TimeoutSeconds.ToString();
   }
   return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```
````